# Better way to get first element of returned array

Tags: php, arrays

I found myself using this:

```
$var=(string)array_shift(array_values($item->xpath($s)));
```

where $s is an xpath search string and the return is an array of objects that contain strings.

It works, but I'm not sure it's the best way to get the data I want.

I could use a tempvar, but I wanted to avoid that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd think that `array_values` is useless here. With PHP 5.4 you can do `$item->xpath($s)[0]`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a variable here? Whats wrong with `$results = $item->xpath($s); $var = (string) $results[0];`?

Comment: @knittl `syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/... line 211` when I tried your version. My php  version might be slightly older than 5.4

Comment: @TecBrat: array subscript on function calls was only added with PHP 5.4 (released today)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Careful with [array_shift](https://www.php.net/array_shift), as it will remove the element from the array stack, if you simply want the first value, you can use [current](https://www.php.net/current):

```
$var = (string) current($item->xpath($s));
```

Comment: Had never seen `current()` before. Thanks. That should be the answer to a lot of "get the first elemen" questions I've see on various PHP forums.

Comment: There is also an `end()` which will get you the last element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this gives the same result.

```
$var=array_shift($item->xpath($s));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $reset($item->xpath($s));
```

Note that this rewinds the array's internal pointer and returns the first element. The method `current` returns the element at the position the pointer happens to be in - it is not guaranteed to always be the first element.